# Outlined text and fill for each instance (Geometry nodes)

Tags: geometry-nodes, text-object

I'm trying to achieve this type of styling on text elements in Geo nodes: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WQp-Kl5jU70 (outlined text + fill)

Here's my setup:

[image]

[image]

I need each letter seperated so I need to check the pick instance boolean, but then the trick of joining the geometry doesn't work anymore.. Any tips on how to fix this?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you always create two objects per letter with your current solution, *Pick Instance* does not work as expected when instantiating.

If you join several elements with `Join Geometry`, they will be recognized and used as single objects when using `Instance on Points`.

However, you can solve this by creating the desired mesh after instantiating the letters.

This could look something like this:

[image]

[image]
<sub>*(Blender 3.2+)*</sub>

Comment: Ah of course! Makes total sense. Thank you so much!